# Evaluation of the double integral $\iint_{[0,1] \times [0,1]}{\left(\frac{xy(1-x)(1-y)}{2-xy}\right)^n \frac{dxdy}{2-xy}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How to prove that

$$\large \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\iint_{[0,1] \times [0,1]}{\left(\frac{xy(1-x)(1-y)}{2-xy}\right)^n \cdot\frac{1}{2-xy}\; \text{d}x\text{d}y}\right)^{\LARGE\frac{1}{n}}=\max_{(x,y)\in [0,1] \times [0,1]} \left \{\frac{xy(1-x)(1-y)}{2-xy}\right \} $$

the inequality $\le$ is direct but the reverse $\ge$ ?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if for $f\geqslant0,g>0$ continuous on $[0,1]^2$ with $f\not\equiv0$ we always have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\iint_{[0,1]^2}f^ng)^{1/n}=\max_{[0,1]^2}f$. Seems reasonable...